# Typeahead support adaptivecards

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

just want to ask if this feature is already supported in microsoft teams?
i have checked on this site :
https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/
adaptive card version has been updated to 1.3. but when i implemented the type ahead support it won't work. Let me know if i have missed anything:

[image]

I am using AdaptiveCardTemplate to render the card:

```
{
""type"": ""AdaptiveCard"",
""body"": [
    {
        ""type"": ""TextBlock"",
        ""size"": ""Large"",
        ""weight"": ""Bolder"",
        ""text"": ""Hey ${sender.first}!"",
        ""wrap"": true
    },
    {
        ""type"": ""TextBlock"",
        ""text"": ""I am not sure what you mean by '${text}'. You can ask me for **help** if you are not sure how to interact with me."",
        ""wrap"": true,
        ""$when"": ""${showProperty}""            
    },
    {
        ""type"": ""TextBlock"",
        ""text"": ""I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand what you wanted.  Can I help you with something or are you looking to get an update on one of your requests?"",
        ""wrap"": true,
        ""$when"": ""${!showProperty}""            
    },
    {
        ""type"": ""Image"",
        ""url"": ""https://picsum.photos/200/200?image=110"",
        ""msTeams"": {
          ""allowExpand"": true
        }
     },
     {
        ""type"": ""Input.ChoiceSet"",
        ""placeholder"": ""Select one or more options"",
        ""isMultiSelect"": false,
        ""choices"": [
           {  ""title"": ""user 1"", ""value"": ""user1"" },
           {  ""title"": ""user 2"", ""value"": ""user2"" }
        ],
        ""style"": ""filtered"",
        ""id"": ""changePriorityOptionsTest2"",
    }
],
""actions"": [
    {
        ""type"": ""Action.ShowCard"",
        ""title"": ""Make a request"",
        ""card"": {
            ""type"": ""AdaptiveCard"",
            ""body"": [
                {
                    ""type"": ""TextBlock"",
                    ""text"": ""Request"",
                    ""weight"": ""Bolder"",
                    ""wrap"": true
                },
                {
                    ""type"": ""TextBlock"",
                    ""text"": ""Maximum 500 characters"",
                    ""wrap"": true,
                    ""size"": ""Small"",
                    ""weight"": ""Lighter""
                },
                {
                    ""type"": ""Input.Text"",
                    ""id"": ""title"",
                    ""value"": ""${text}"",
                    ""placeholder"": ""Add a title"",
                    ""isMultiline"": true,
                    ""spacing"": ""none""
                },
                {
                    ""type"": ""TextBlock"",
                    ""text"": ""Priority"",
                    ""weight"": ""Bolder"",
                    ""wrap"": true,
                },
                {
                    ""type"": ""Input.ChoiceSet"",
                    ""isMultiSelect"": true,
                    ""choices"": [
                        {
                            ""$data"": ""${priorityOptions}"",
                            ""title"": ""${Value}"",
                            ""value"": ""${Id}""
                        }
                    ],
                    ""value"": ""${priorityId}"",
                    ""id"": ""changePriorityOptions"",
                    ""style"": ""compact"",
                }
            ],
            ""actions"": [
                {
                    ""type"": ""Action.Submit"",
                    ""title"": ""Submit"",
                    ""id"": ""CreateTicket"",
                    ""data"": { ""title"": ""${title}"", ""commandId"": ""CreateTicket"" }
                }
            ],
            ""$schema"": ""http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json""
        },
        ""$when"": ""${!showProperty}""
    },
    {
        ""type"": ""Action.Submit"",
        ""title"": ""Status of my requests"",
        ""id"": ""MyTickets"",
        ""data"": { ""text"": ""${text}"", ""commandId"": ""MyTickets"" },
        ""$when"": ""${!showProperty}""
    }
],
""$schema"": ""http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"",
""version"": ""1.2"",
""msteams"": {
    ""width"": ""Full""
},
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes,Typeahead support(which simplify input selection by narrowing or filtering the set of input choices as the user types the input) is already supported in Microsoft Teams. Tried with 1.1,1.2 and 1.3 version of adaptive card and each case it worked fine. Attaching my adaptive card sample for reference.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
    {
      "speak": "Tom's Pie is a pizza restaurant which is rated 9.3 by customers.",
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "PIZZA"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Tom's Pie",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "extraLarge",
              "spacing": "none"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "4.2 ★★★☆ (93) · $$",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "spacing": "none"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "**Matt H. said** \"I'm compelled to give this place 5 stars due to the number of times I've chosen to eat here this past year!\"",
              "size": "small",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
              "label": "Select a user",
              "isMultiSelect": false,
              "choices": [
                {
                  "title": "User 1",
                  "value": "User1"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 2",
                  "value": "User2"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 3",
                  "value": "User3"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 4",
                  "value": "User4"
                },
                {
                  "title": "User 5",
                  "value": "User5"
                }
              ],
              "style": "filtered"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 1,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://picsum.photos/300?image=882",
              "size": "auto"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
      "title": "More Info",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How did you do it? i basically udpated version to 1.4 but still i got no typeahead feature reflecting. my adaptive card extension is also udpated. can you show me what other configurations you have? Thank you.

Comment: I used the same json as mentioned in the answer section in adaptive card. Sent that adaptive card to Teams Channel and was able to filter the input choices